# How many times must I satisfy the pope's demands?

Tags: bead-machine-punktasia

My first encounter with the pope was bad enough, but hitting him again the second time it's going to take me ages to meet his demands. How many times does he come around in total?

Comment: The second time you meet the pope, you have access to Puzzlers.  With those, you can lost stuff just as fast as you can gain it.  Much easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is a limit on the number of Popes you can meet.  However, each Pope will give you 1 Enlightenment.

That said, the most Enlightenment you need for the main storyline is 5.  However, there is an achievement for getting 10 Enlightenment.

Comment: Popes are the worst.